# How to download a file from server with a button click

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, download

Let's say I have this file on my server:

```
server/myFile.txt
```

How can I make the user download it with a button click?
Am I missing a simple solution?

I am using jQuery & PHP if there is a solution for that.

thanks,
Alon

Comment: jquery trigger('click') on a hidden link?

Comment: I know how to do $('#myLink').click(function(){}); my question is what do I write to make the file download command

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to force a "save-as" dialog box to open for a file type that your web server is configured to output as a readable document (and you don't want to change that configuration), you need to create a file that modifies the headers so that the browser creates such a dialog.

See the very first example in the php documentation for [readfile](http://php.net/manual/en/function.readfile.php).

You would then create a PHP file that could be accessed through a normal `a href` link, which would send the appropriate headers and output `myFile.txt`.

Answer (score 4):

I am not sure if I am misunderstanding your question otherwise it should be as simple as:

```
<a href="link/to/file">download file</a>
```

You shouldn't need to use js or php at all, Apache or whatever other webserver you are using should take care of handling the download all by itself. Simply let the user download it straight off the server.

Comment: I want to have a button that says "download file" and when I click on it then the file will be downloaded to the user's computer like here: http://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/new/. the href attr only redirects me to the file location but doesn't download the file..

Comment: What webserver are you using? If you are using apache then you can force downloads by using a technique as described in http://www.thingy-ma-jig.co.uk/comment/7186 otherwise it can also be achieved in php by http://www.ryboe.com/tutorials/php-headers-force-download

Comment: Maybe is better to specify that "link/to/file" should be a link based on your website. For example, if you have your website under /var/www/www.mywebsite.com and the file to be downloaded under /var/www/www.mywebsite.com/files/myfile.txt, the real value of "link/to/file" should be "http://www.mywebsite.com/files/myfile.txt". If you'll use the base path (ie "/var/www/www.mywebsite.com/files/myfile.txt") you'll end up with "http://www.mywebsite.com/var/www/www.mywebsite.com/files/myfile.txt" which is not the right path.

Comment: @Alon, Add `content-disposition:attachment` to the header and the browser will download it instead of display it.